# Using Tensorflow's "tf.gather" and "tf.gradients" together

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I want to compute the gradients of tensor "Y" with respect to parameter matrix "X" in Tensorflow. Specifically, I want to compute the gradients only for a given set of "indices" of "X". The following code computes the entire gradient first, then returns those gradients corresponding to the desired indices:

```
Y=some_function_of_X
grad=tf.gradients(Y,X)
grads_i_want_to_compute=tf.gather(grad,indices)
```

Using Tensorflow's "tf.scatter_sub", I can then update the desired indices of the parameter matrix "X" based on gradient descent:

```
tf.scatter_sub(X,indices,learning_rate*grads_i_want_to_compute)
```

this works properly, but at the end of the day all the gradients are computed! For the sake of processing speed I do not want to compute all the gradients. So I tried this:

```
Y=some_function_of_X
sparse_X=tf.gather(X,indices)
grads_i_want_to_compute = tf.gradient(Y,sparse_X)
tf.scatter_sub(X,indices,learning_rate*grads_i_want_to_compute)
```

In the latter, "tf.gradient" returns "None" objects so I cannot proceed. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you need Y to be a function of sparse_X, not a function of X.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split X into a set of smaller tensors then compute

Y = f(tf.concat(list_of_X_i, ...))

then compute gradients w.r.t. each of the X_i that you care about. It might not be practical or efficient for what you are trying to do.

Another thing to consider is that depending on the depth and structure of the network, a gradient for a single element in X may depend on many (or even all) of the gradients from the layers above. So you may not save a lot of computation compared to the brute force approach.